# MAVEN - Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.2:run (default-cli)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am working with springboot, and I get this error. Have been fixing this for hours but I still cannot find the solution. The error shows when I try to `mvn clean install`,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) on project mdb-spring-boot:
```

and when I try to mvn spring-boot:run, this error shows

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.2:run (default-cli) on project mdb-spring-boot: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

this is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mdb-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mdb-spring-boot</name>
    <description>Spring boot mongodb</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

thanks a lot!!

> I have searched a lot of solutions here, but nothing fixes my error.

Comment: Remove the surefire plugin (spring boot already has this). Remove the `version` for the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` it will be managed by Spring BOot (and currently you are mixing versions of Spring Boot).

Comment: okay, thank you I will try this!!